# Passing parameters to a trigger function

Tags: postgresql, triggers

I can't figure out how to pass parameters to a trigger function.

I checked the documentation and saw that trigger functions don't take
params in the usual fashion,
but couldn't find an example of a pl-sql trigger function that used
the original row data within the function.

***My example:***

```
CREATE TABLE emp (
    id serial,
    empname text,
    salary integer,
    last_date timestamp,
    last_user text
);



CREATE FUNCTION emp_stamp() RETURNS trigger AS '
    BEGIN
        -- Check that empname and salary are given
        IF NEW.empname IS NULL THEN
            RAISE EXCEPTION ''empname cannot be null'';
        END IF;
        IF NEW.salary IS NULL THEN
            RAISE EXCEPTION ''% cannot have null salary'', NEW.empname;
        END IF;



        -- Who works for us when she must pay for it?
        IF NEW.salary < 0 THEN
            RAISE EXCEPTION ''% cannot have a negative salary'', NEW.empname;
        END IF;



        -- Remember who changed the payroll when
        NEW.last_date := ''now'';
        NEW.last_user := current_user;
        RETURN NEW;
    END;
' LANGUAGE plpgsql;



CREATE TRIGGER emp_stamp BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON emp
    FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE emp_stamp();
```

Comment: just use `OLD.column_name`    ex: `NEW.count_update = OLD.count_update +1;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the documentation describes, `NEW` and `OLD` are defined in row level triggers and contain the affected table row after (for `INSERT` and `UPDATE` triggers) and before (for `UPDATE` and `INSERT` triggers) the data modification.

You don't have to pass them to the trigger function, they are defined automatically.

In a `BEFORE` trigger, you can simply modify `NEW` to change the new row (you do *not* update the table in a `BEFORE` trigger).

To get the original row in a trigger, simply use the values in `OLD`.